# Using Haskell's Turtle to Call a Custom Bash Function

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Using turtle, how does one run a custom bash command found in `/a/path/to/a/file.sh`? It would be the equivalent of `source /a/path/to/a/file.sh` and then calling `custom_bash_function`.

Comment: I don't know turtle, but I'd just go through bash. `bash -c 'source /a/path/to/a/file.sh; custom_bash_function'`

Comment: and run @luqui 's command via the `turtle` command `exec` or `shell`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle.Prelude (proc, procs, shell, shells)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  procs "ls" [] mempty         --(without ExitCode)
  procs "ls" ["-la"] mempty    --(without ExitCode)
  proc "pwd" [] mempty         --(with ExitCode)
  proc "ls" ["-la"] mempty     --(with ExitCode)

  shells "ls -la" mempty       --(without ExitCode)
  shell "pwd" mempty           --(with ExitCode)
  shell "ls -la" mempty        --(with ExitCode)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all. Did you post it by mistake?